# I have a sql server with a pictures table with 25 million entries and it has become too slow to query. currently have a xeon E5-2667v3 with 32g of ram

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, sql, hp-proliant

I have a sql server with a pictures table with 25 million entries and it has become too slow to query i currently have a Xeon E5-2667v3 with 32g of ram, I am looking to get a hp ProLiant Gen 9 and I am not sure how to go with specs, is SQL single or multi-threaded? would I benefit from going many weaker cores or less stronger cores? does ram have a large effect? should I get more ram or faster ram? What about caching?

Any help is much appreciated
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question appears to be looking for a product recommendation, which is [generally considered off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). The StackExchange Q&A sites are intended for providing specific answers to specific problems. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider substantially revising or deleting your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: First structure your database properly, then get the proper hardware. Take a look at partitioning.

Comment: I'm certain any new server would outperform seven year old hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Well the RAM is irrelevant - at the end tit runs down on developer competence (https://use-the-index-luke.com/) and IO performance. Know what you do not talk about? IO PERFORMANCE. Like "all Super Fast SSD setup".

CPU good enough? WHO KNOWS. You should - you can easily measure CPU utilization, but even if that is 100% - it means nothing because it could also mean someone with less knowledge than a used car salesman has about SQL has writte nextremely bad and performance killing (CPU intensive) queries. Been there, seen that.

Also, what is too slow - HOW MANY QUERIES IN PARALLEL? An E5 2667 is nice. It is still a low end processor. Even with efficient queries, and super fast IO, there is a limit how much you can throw on a low end server and expect it to perform. DO YOUR JOB - measure, estimate. Do not expect us to help you without any idea what you talk about. Maybe you can optimize the queries - and STILL need 128 cores, no 8. WHO KNOWS EXCEPT YOU?